# React scroll event that has access to State

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to build an infinite scroll component in React (specifically using NextJS). I am having trouble with this feature because when I set a scroll event on the window, it doesn't have access to updated state. How can I write a scroll event that listens to any scrolling on the entire window that also has access to state like router query params?

Here's some code to see what I'm trying to do:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  },[]);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const el = infiniteScroll.current;
    if (el) {
      const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      const isVisible =
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <=
          (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <=
          (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);

      if (isVisible && !isComplete && !isFetching) {
        nextPage();
      }
    }
  };

  const nextPage = () => {
    const params = router.query as any;  // <------ these params here never update with state and are locked in to the the values they were at when the component mounted
    params.page = params.page
      ? (parseInt((params as any).page) + 1).toString()
      : '1';
    router.replace(router, undefined, { scroll: false });
  };
```

The issue is that the `router` value is locked at the place it was when the component mounted.

I've tried removing the empty array of dependencies for the `useEffect` at the top, but as you can imagine, this creates multiple scroll listeners and my events fire too many times. I've tried removing the eventListener before adding it every time, but it still fires too many times.

Every example I've found online seems to not need access to state variables, so they write code just like this and it works for them.

Any ideas how I can implement this?

I've tried to use the `onScroll` event, but it doesn't work unless you have a fixed height on the container so that you can use `overflow-y: scroll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ref to access and modify your state in the scope of the handleScroll function.

Here is how:

```
const yourRef = useRef('foo');

useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
        const value = yourRef.current;

        if (value === 'foo') {
            yourRef.current = 'bar'
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: I think this is probably a better answer since useRef is more performant

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out that works. Posting in case anyone else is having the same issue.

I created a custom hook called `useScrollPosition` that sets a listener on the window and updates the scroll position. It looks like this:

```
const useScrollPosition = () => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatePosition = () => {
      setScrollPosition(window.pageYOffset);
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);
    updatePosition();
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);
  }, []);

  return scrollPosition;
};
```

and using that in my component like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    handleScroll();
  }, [scrollPosition]);
```

allows me to access the current state of the `router`